# Calling route after previous one finishes in camel context

Tags: apache-camel

I'm writing one camel application using blueprint.I have two routes which calls same class beans but for different case(Handled that in class based on route id).I want to start second route only when first route completes it's execution(sequentially instead of parallel).So is there any way to do the same.Following is my code-

```
<camelContext id="test"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="1">
        <from uri="timer"/>
        <to uri="bean:test"/>
    </route>
    <route id="2">
       <from uri="timer"/>
       <to uri="bean:test"/>  
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use different methods on the same bean?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele -Thanks for your reply.But for that I'll have to make a lot of changes as the application is pretty complex.So can you please suggest a way to start route 2 only after route 1 finishes.

Comment: The *from route 1 to route 2* concept is exchange level. Both routes must be started for an exchange to go through them. You're looking for a different pattern, not different routes or route structure.

Answer (score 1):

Routes are started when camel context is bootstrapped. You're probably looking for the exchange to be routed to "route2" after it's been processed by "route1"

That sounds like the same route. You have a few options for reusing a bean while implementing different behavior. The easiest one IMO from where you are is using different methods:

```
class TestBean {
    void test1(){}
    void test2(){}
}
```

Then changing your route config:

```
<route id="1">
    <from uri="timer"/>
    <to uri="bean:test?method=test1"/>
    <to uri="bean:test?method=test2"/>  
</route>
```

Of course you can change to make these be different beans...